# Mushroom Identification (USA)

Tags: species-identification, mycology

I would like some help identifying this mushroom I found in my yard. 
Location: Southeast Georgia
Near Pine trees after heavy rainfall
Color: Light brown to Dark Red, biggest is about 4 inches in radius

[image: top]
[image: bottom]
[image: side]

Answer (score -1):

It is some type of boletus. You would need a spore print and a few more examples to decide which one. They are commonly found under conifers.The books say most are editable and good taste. The couple kind I have eaten had no flavor , not worth collecting. The tubes instead of gills on the bottom of the cap are an indicator of boletus group.

Comment: I agree it looks like a bolete, but your post needs to provide citations to support your claims and should ideally give a more direct answer as yoru answer currently is conjectural and not actually answering the OP's question. Please do some additional research and [edit] your post with more info. Thanks!